# Remove original battery indicator from indicator applet

Tags: indicator, gnome-power-manager

I've added battery-status to the indicator applet, but I am having trouble removing the original battery applet (stuck on "estimating"), and I currently have two battery icons in the indicator applet.  Going through the preferences of the original power applet, there is an option to never show the icon, but that options makes both icons disappear and leaves an empty space in the indicator applet, which acts like battery-status, that is its fully functional, but lacks the battery picture.

This website:
http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/02/battery-applet-status-ubuntu/

claims that when I add battery-status to the indicator, I should be prompted to replace the original indicator but no such prompt appeared.

I also removed gnome-power-manager=1 from /usr/share/indicator-application/ordering-override.keyfile but that changed nothing (What exactly does removing that line even do, for curiosity's sake?)

The answer posted by Madhava is no good.  I've already mentioned that doing what you are showing me makes the icon disappear for the battery-status as well as the original battery indicator. Here is a video of this:

http://img860.imageshack.us/i/7mi.mp4

How do I get the battery-status icon to remain, and not just a blank space??

Answer (score 5):

Open **System Settings**. In the Hardware section, click **Power Management**. Switch to the **General** tab and select "Never display an icon".

[image]

Comment: This is not the answer I was looking for.  I've already mentioned that doing what you are showing me makes the icon disappear for the battery-status as well as the original battery indicator.  Here is a video of this:

http://img860.imageshack.us/i/7mi.mp4/

How do I get the battery-status icon to remain, and not just a blank space??